# Display a CLRegion on a map view

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

I have a region of of a CLPlacemark declared by

```
let placeRegion = placemark?.region
```

[According to the Apple docs this is](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clplacemark/1423808-region)

> The geographic region associated with the placemark.

Is it possible to display this region on a map view?

I am not actually sure what a region of a placemark is. Does anyone know if it is just a circular region with a fixed radius around the placemark, or is the region shape sometimes tailored to match the real-life area of the place, for example, the shape of the building of the place?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would depend on the origin of the CLPlacemark.  While most will come back as CLCircularRegion, you could define a custom CLRegion class that fits a different shape with multiple coordinates and map coordinates from the custom CLRegion to [MKPolygon](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkpolygon) to display the region on the map view.

Comment: Hey thanks, I am very new to Swift btw. So basically I need to check if the CLRegion is a CLCircularRegion and use MKCircle if it is, and if not I then I use MKPolygon? If the region isn't circular how do I then find the coordinates of the vertices to make the MKPolygon?

Comment: Right on the money. If you're pulling the placemark from a third party that hasn't defined a custom CLRegion, then you will almost certainly be using a CLCircularRegion and MKCircle.  If you are custom generating your own CLPlacemark objects then you have more control over the structure but if you're using something like https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder then it'll be a circle if you get anything. Would be real nice if future iOS versions included some more CLRegion derived classes.

Comment: That's great. So what might be the first step in checking if the CLRegion is circular?

Comment: if region.isKind(of: CLCircularRegion.self) { ... } would be one way